# Doesn’t look like a character based (Bytes Are All You Need) model (DeepSpeech)

Tags: machine-learning, utf-8, neural-network, mozilla-deepspeech

I have been following DeepSpeech documentation in order to build my own scorer. After implementing this blocks of code

> cd data/lm
> python3 generate_lm.py --input_txt vocabulary.txt --output_dir .
> –top_k 1500 --kenlm_bins path/to/kenlm/build/bin/
> –arpa_order 3 --max_arpa_memory “50%” --arpa_prune “0|0|1”
> –binary_a_bits 255 --binary_q_bits 8 --binary_type trie
>
> curl -LO [http://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases/…](http://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases/%E2%80%A6)
> tar xvf native_client.*.tar.xz
> ./generate_scorer_package --alphabet …/alphabet.txt --lm lm.binary --vocab vocab-1500.txt
> –package kenlm.scorer --default_alpha 0.931289039105002 --default_beta 1.1834137581510284

I get the following errors:

> Doesn’t look like a character based (Bytes Are All You Need) model.
> –force_bytes_output_mode was not specified, using value infered from vocabulary contents: false
> Error: Can’t parse scorer file, invalid header. Try updating your scorer file.
> Error loading language model file: Invalid magic in trie header.

I want to mention that I use a different alphabet that also contains other characters besides english characters.

Answer (score 2):

This error is usually encountered with non-English alphabets. You can overcome the error by using the `--force_bytes_output_mode` parameter when calling `generate_scorer_package`. I pushed a [change to the PlayBook](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/SCORER.html#building-your-own-scorer) this morning which covers this error.